# How to pass the JSON object as input string to a post method in IDHTTP using Delphi

Tags: c#, json, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, idhttp

" I need to send the JSON object to a URL using the Post method of the IDHTTP in Delphi. I am facing error while I try to send the JSON object string Directly along with the URL."

```
 [HttpPost]
        public bool SaveTestCases(String testCases)
        {
           //some codes

            return false;
        }
the above given is the post URL in the c# with the input string.
I am trying to send the JSON string as input to the URL from the IDHTTP post method.

procedure TfrmTestcases.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  http : TIdHTTP;
  ReqJson: TStringStream;
  data : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  data := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  ReqJson:= TStringStream.Create(DummyArray,TEncoding.UTF8);
  //dummyarray contain the Json string {"name":"abcd efgh","ID":"1"}
  http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  http.Post('https://LocalHost/user/SaveTestCases?testCases='+DummyArray,ReqJson);
end;
```

" here I am getting the HTTP 400 error that is due to space in between the "name" in the DummyArray string. Is there any other way to send the JSON 
    object as input to the above-given C# post method"

Comment: You won't get any help if you dont show MCVE

Comment: @Fero68 I have added the MCVE please help me out.

Comment: First of all I dont think this code even compiles by looking at the Post method